# TFS Sub-area name change

Tags: tfs

I would like to know if its possible to edit the name of a sub-area in TFS. I know I can create new areas and delete but I can't seem to find a way to rename. There might be implications around this that would keep someone from performing this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS 2012, you should be able to go the same screen you create the areas and double click (or right click on select edit) on the area you want to rename. At that point, you should be able to modify the name accordingly.